# Is it possible to fully restrict/disable apps when they are closed?

Tags: applications, task-management, background-process

I would love to have more control over when apps can run on my Android: I wish that apps can't run in background, unless I whitelist them, or unless I am using them.

"Background Restriction" offers something similar. But it kills the restricted apps when they're placed in background: I can't simply leave them open, running in the background, until I close them.

For example, I want my music player to be fully dead when I'm not using it: I don't want it to run processes in the background. But when I'm using it, it should stay alive until I close it, even if its activity is not in the foreground.
This experience is very natural on desktop computers: most programs work while you leave their window open (background or foreground doesn't matter) and die as soon as you close it. I wish to have it on Android too, but Background Restriction doesn't quite offer it.

The "Recents Screen" seems like the perfect tool for what I need: only the apps in the Recents Screen (and those whitelisted) should be allowed to run. As soon as I remove one from the Recents Screen, it should get killed and become fully restricted.

- Can I obtain my desired behavior by tweaking some configuration or by installing some software?
- Otherwise, would it be possible to implement it myself? I think it'd be enough to have a tiny script listening to/polling the Recents Screen and toggling the Background Restriction setting for apps as they are added to/removed from the Recents Screen. Are there any APIs to do this available from e.g. bash or python, without needing to create a full fledged app?

I'm using rooted phones with Android 11 and the stock ROM (I have a Pixel 3XL and a Nexus 5X). A rootless solution would be better of course. I'm willing to change ROM, if that's a solution.

Comment: To be honest I'd say since Android was ment to be a do it all OS, the recents menu wasn't meant to work exactly how you'd want it to work. The folks developing the OS ar pretty smart and if it was as simple as just opening a process and terminating it when swiped out they would've done that.   Furthermore many times in Windows when you close a program it still runs stuff in th background.  Lastly, there exists some programs that force close apps when not in use but they bring many unwanted behaviors and in my opinion don't save that much battery.

Comment: Be aware that OEM's battery optimizers as described in: https://dontkillmyapp.com/ which act similar to what you describe break the API contract between the Android framework and developers, but as it is your intent - just be ready to accept that certain apps won't work correctly. It would probably help to know which phone/OS version you are running.

Comment: I would whitelist apps that I care about, trust and want them to work properly. But I also have a bunch of apps that I need to use for a short session every several days and I want these apps to be as dead as if they were uninstalled when they're not in use: music player (I only use it when travelling: a couple of hours every few weeks), app to control my camera (I use it maybe once a month), app for the vacuum cleaner (once a week for half an hour) and more. They keep some processes alive in the background. I don't want this. I would uninstall them every time, but un&installing is too slow.

Comment: I have two phones at the moment, a Pixel 3 XL and a Nexus 5x. Both rooted, with the stock ROM.

Comment: Stock ROM doesn't tell anyone which version of Android. Assuming you are using a recent/updated one on the Pixel 3 XL, look at `App Standby Buckets` via 'developer mode' & `adb`: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/power#buckets and see if 'rare bucket' is acceptable.

Comment: Ohh, sorry, Android version 11.
I'll check out the rare bucket.